# communicate with google maps app android development

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, kotlin

I am currently working on an app which should communicate with google maps for navigation.
For the moment, I send an intent with an uri to maps on which it opens and navigates to the points I told maps to go to.
When I receive data updates (in a backend context, external input), I might want to change the route.
Can I send an intent to update the route without just creating a new route?

When I currently send a new intent to open a new route, maps first asks to terminate the current route, I want to be able to just display: "Your route has been updated" or something like that.

I'm currently not really worried about opening a socket towards my backend for updates etc, I just want to know whether communication to Google Maps is possible without having to "exit current navigation".

I'm using Googles Directions API so I can't use an integrated turn by turn navigation in app because of Googles policy.

Thanks in advance